# Can I map to memory the seekable character device `/dev/mem_8` and access to it by using x86_64 instructions?

Tags: c++, c, linux, x86, mmap

If I have a seekable character device - `/dev/mem_8`, allowing a user-space program random access to the memory array with simple I/O operations, can I map it to the virtual addressing memory of my process to ease access to it by using x86_64 instructions: `MOV`, `REP MOVS`, and SSE: `MOVNTDQ`, `MOVNTDQA` ... ?

OS: Linux x86_64 kernel >= 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you successfully called the [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) syscall from inside your Linux (user-mode) application, your [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) has changed and every (non-privileged) machine instruction (from your process which did the `mmap`) can access it since a [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) works in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

You may use the [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) filesystem to query the address space, e.g. with `cat /proc/$PID/maps` ....

If your `/dev/mem_8` is `mmap`able it should be ok. Perhaps better make it a [block device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_device#Block_devices) if possible. Or maybe provide a [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem (to provide the block-like abstraction above your char device)....

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) ...

Perhaps [raw(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/raw.8.html) is relevant... (not sure of that).

Comment: Thanks! But for what I can use `cat /proc/$PID/maps` in my case, and why better to bind a Linux raw character device `/dev/mem_8` to a block device and uses block device?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand all about virtual memory. And `cat /proc/$PID/maps` may help you to understand that, and to check that your code has the address space you want it to have.